# How to dynamically change the number of cores to use per Spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two related Spark tasks in Python using the same SparkContext. Is there a way to set one task to use specific set of cores (one core from each machine) and the other task to use another specific set of cores (one core from each machine). The cores used by the two tasks should be not shared, but the one task could use the RDD created by the other task.

Is there any way that this could be done?

Comment: Not really. Could you explain why do you want something like this? Especially at the task level.

Comment: I have an RDD that is used by one task and this RDD is updated periodically by another task. I would like to separate the cores used by the two RDDs because the update operation can be quite expensive, and this takes up computing resources away from the other task that I want to keep working quickly at all times.
Maybe I'm not using the terminologies correctly as I'm a beginner in Spark...